# variable array is only populating last row of mysql table

Tags: php

I am calling back the results for AnswerStatusID and AnswerResponse and need to apply them to a variable to compare against to see if the answer given is correct or incorrect and the corresponding response for the answer, my issue is that my variable is only being populated by the last row in the table instead of populating it with all of the data.

```
// Connect to the Database
require_once('mysqli_connect.php');

//create the query for the question
$q = "SELECT `Question` FROM tbl_Question WHERE QuestionID = 1";

//Create the query for the Answers
$q2 = "SELECT `Answer`,`AnswerStatusID`,`AnswerResponse` FROM tbl_Answer WHERE QuestionID = 1";


//Run the query
$r = mysqli_query($conn,$q);

//run the answer query
$r2 = mysqli_query($conn,$q2);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo '<div id="Question1"><p>1) ' . $row['Question'] . '</div></p>';
}



while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r2,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo '<div id="Question1"><input name="q1" type="radio" value="'.$AnswerStatusID.'"/>' . $row2['Answer'] . '</div><br/>';

//Assign the AnswerStatusID to a var
$AnswerStatusID = $row2['AnswerStatusID'];

//Assign the AnswerResponse to a var
$AnswerResponse = $row2['AnswerResponse'];
}
```

Comment: So, do you want `$AnswerStatusID` and `$AnswerResponse` to be arrays of all the StatusIDs and Responses?

Comment: your variables are being set to all rows, but because you are using a scaler, all but the last get overwritten by the last.

Comment: @Wiseguy yes that is exactly what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Wiseguy intimated, it looks like you want AnswerStatusID and AnswerResponse as arrays.

Two steps here. First declare them as arrays.

```
$AnswerResponse = array();
$AnswerStatusID = array();
```

Then store the values in each of them

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r2,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo '<div id="Question1"><input name="q1" type="radio" value="'.$AnswerStatusID.'"/>' . $row2['Answer'] . '</div><br/>';

    //Assign the AnswerStatusID to a var
    $AnswerStatusID[] = $row2['AnswerStatusID'];

    //Assign the AnswerResponse to a var
    $AnswerResponse[] = $row2['AnswerResponse'];
}
```

You can then see what's in the arrays using var_dump();

```
var_dump($AnswerResponse)
```

or

```
print_r($AnswerResponse)
```

Comment: I tried that and when I echoed it to see the results and ensure that the variable was populated the echo was "array" and not any data

Comment: echo '<p>' .$AnswerResponse . '</p>';
echo '<p>' .$AnswerStatusID . '</p>';

Comment: That's a good thing! You can use var_dump($AnswerResponse) or echo print_r($AnswerResponse) to see what's in the arrays.

Comment: oh so that behavior is what SHOULD happen if the array is populated? I thought is would echo all the results with what I tried